# Хранимая процедура из кода c# в EF(Code First)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть контекст данных и инициализатор данных,

```
public class ShoopProductContext: DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public DbSet<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class shoopProductsInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ShoopProductContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ShoopProductContext context)
    {
        context.Products.Add(new Product { NameProduct = "11" });//Тут должна быть ХП
        context.SaveChanges();// 
    }
}
```

нужно заполнить таблицу данными через ХП, в инициализаторе данных. У меня вопросы:

1. Как создать ХП в коде с# в EF(Code first)?
2. Можно ли добавить ХП, в
   бд при подходе Code first в инициализаторе данных?
3. Как её(ХП)
   запустить из кода(C#)?
4. Можно ли в этой ХП создать триггер и
   привязать его к таблице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в CodeFirst есть возможность создавать прямые запросы к БД через передачу SQL кода. Для этого можно использовать [context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, Object[] param)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx). Вызов хранимой процедуры происходит так же.

Если надо вернуть данные, то вызов происходит через метод [context.Database.SqlQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx), который так же имеют объекты DbSet. Но при этом надо знать возвращаемый тип на который будет мапиться ответ.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
create or replace function TestFunction()
returns setof ""Test"" as 
$$
begin
   return query select ...
end;
$$ language plpgsql
");

context.SaveChanges();
```

И вызов без привязки к данным.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select TestFunction()", null);
```

Или вызов с привязкой к данным.

```
context.Test.SqlQuery("select * from TestFunction()").First();
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. Так же через Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() можно добавлять и треггеры?